# How can I get these pins description?

Tags: datasheet, pins, camera, pinout

How can I get these pins' descriptions? I researched on the internet a lot but I couldn't find anything. Here is the datasheet [PDF download link](http://www.wonwoo.com/en/product/product_view.php?idx=684&part1_idx=2&part2_idx=15&part3_idx=) and [website](http://www.wonwoo.com/en/product/product_view.php?idx=684&part1_idx=2&part2_idx=15&part3_idx=).

I specially need camera control pins. I will get the video data through SDI (another connector).

[image: pins]

Comment: You ask the descriptions from the manufacturer. The manufacturer implements protocols made by other companies like Sony VISCA or Pelco protocols, and the specifications of those protocols may not be open and implementable without permission.

Comment: Okay, I will ask to manufacturer but if it is private information, why they share the pinout of the connector ..? I thought these pin names are universal or something. Anyways thanks